# How can I store the data given by loops in an array [PHP]

Tags: php, loops

I have a normal for loop that echo's the iterator "$i", I want to know how I can store does numbers in an array(), below is what I've tried, but it only stores the first digit in the array(0). I tried "for" loops and "while" loops.

```
$array = array();

for ($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++){
$array[] = $i;
}
echo $array[0];
```

I'm not sure what to do exactly, I would want to store the digits of this loop echos which are numbers 1-10 respectably. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I understand I made a mistake in my question, the example I gave is not a "for each" loop, it's a "for" loop. My apologies

Comment: Try `print_r($array);` at the end.

Comment: You only `echo` the first element of the array with `$array[0]`? Try `var_dump($array)`

Comment: It's storing just fine. Your confusion is how to then _access_ those stored values.

Comment: I'll have to try that, but I'm skeptical since I've also tried echoing $array[1] and so on, but I wouldn't get anything.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickQ, I'll try it now with the answers provided.

Comment: Also (just to be pedantic) it will store 0-10, not 1-10

Comment: Yes I just realized, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You may be aware of this already, but a loop isn't necessary to create that array.

```
$array = range(1, 10);   // or 0, 10 if that's what you need
```

Comment: I was aware you didn't need a loop, just not that a range() function existed for this matter. Very useful thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_push function and push the elements into the array as in the following code, although your code is storing all the elements in the array. Try to use var_dump and check.

```
$array = array();

for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++){
    array_push($array, $i);
}

var_dump($array);
```